WebRTC on Track not working on client side
I have setup webrtc backend with which I am connecting the client side. The connection get works fine and an audio track has been initialised and I get that event on clinet side. After that I add audio data on backend but dont receive on clientside.
Backend Code
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const { Server } = require('http');
const wrtc = require('wrtc');
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');

const server = Server();
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

let rtcPeerConnection;
let globalAudioSource;
let isGeneratingAudio = false;
let wsConnection;

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('WebSocket connection established');
  wsConnection = ws;

  ws.on('message', async (message) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(message);

    // Handle SDP offer from frontend
    if (data.type === 'offer') {
      console.log('Received SDP offer:', data.sdp);
      rtcPeerConnection = new wrtc.RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: [
          { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }, // Add a STUN server
        ],
      });

      rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
        console.log('Received ICE candidate:', event.candidate);
        if (event.candidate) {
          console.log('Sending ICE candidate:', event.candidate);
          ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'ice-candidate', candidate: event.candidate }));
        }
      };

      rtcPeerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
        console.log('Received track:', event.track.kind);
      };

      try {
        await rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new wrtc.RTCSessionDescription(data.sdp));
        console.log('Remote SDP set successfully');

        // Create a global audio source and track to be negotiated upfront
        globalAudioSource = new wrtc.nonstandard.RTCAudioSource();
        const audioTrack = globalAudioSource.createTrack();
        rtcPeerConnection.addTrack(audioTrack);
        console.log('Audio track added to PeerConnection during negotiation:', audioTrack);

        const answer = await rtcPeerConnection.createAnswer();
        await rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);

        console.log('Sending SDP answer:', rtcPeerConnection.localDescription);
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'answer', sdp: rtcPeerConnection.localDescription }));
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error handling SDP offer:', error);
      }
    }

    // Handle ICE candidate from frontend
    if (data.type === 'ice-candidate' && rtcPeerConnection) {
      console.log('Received ICE candidate from frontend:', data.candidate);
      if (data.candidate) {
        await rtcPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(data.candidate);
        console.log('Added ICE candidate');
      }
    }

    // Handle text for TTS
    if (data.type === 'text') {
      if (rtcPeerConnection && globalAudioSource) {
        if (isGeneratingAudio) {
          console.warn('Audio generation in progress. Skipping additional requests.');
          return;
        }
    
        try {
          isGeneratingAudio = true; // Block new requests
          console.log('Generating audio for text:', data.text);

          // Stream TTS audio data to the existing audio track
          await streamAudioData(globalAudioSource, data.text);
          console.log('Audio generation completed');
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error generating audio track:', error);
        } finally {
          console.log('Audio generation completed and audio track is ready');
          isGeneratingAudio = false; // Allow new requests
        }
      } else {
        console.error('rtcPeerConnection is not initialized');
      }
    }
    
  });
});



async function streamAudioData(audioSource, text) {
  try {
    console.log('Received audio data from Deepgram API');

    const rawBuffer = fs.readFileSync('./audio/audio.mp4');
    const pcmBuffer = rawBuffer.subarray(44);

    // Now pcmBuffer contains just the raw PCM data
    const audioData = new Int16Array(pcmBuffer.buffer, pcmBuffer.byteOffset, pcmBuffer.byteLength / 2);
    const chunkSize = 480; // 10ms at 48kHz
    let offset = 0;

    wsConnection.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'audio-start' }));

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (offset >= audioData.length) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          wsConnection.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'audio-end' }));
          resolve();
          return;
        }

        const chunk = audioData.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize);
        const mySamples = new Int16Array(chunkSize);
        mySamples.set(chunk);

        audioSource.onData({
          samples: mySamples,
          sampleRate: 48000
        });

        offset += chunkSize;
      }, 10);
      console.log('Audio streaming complete');
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error streaming audio data:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on port 8080');
});

and this is the frontend code
'use client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function HomePage() {
  const [ws, setWs] = useState(null);
  const [rtc, setRtc] = useState(null);
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [offerReady, setOfferReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ws) {
      ws.onmessage = async (event) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(event.data);

        // Handle SDP answer from backend
        if (data.type === 'answer' && rtc) {
          // console.log('Received SDP answer from backend:', data.sdp);
          await rtc.setRemoteDescription(data.sdp);
        }

        // Handle ICE candidate from backend
        if (data.type === 'ice-candidate' && rtc) {
          if (!data.candidate) {
            // console.log('ICE candidate gathering complete');
            return; // Skip processing null candidates
          }
          // console.log('Received ICE candidate from backend:', data.candidate);
          await rtc.addIceCandidate(data.candidate);
          console.log('Added ICE candidate');
        }

        if (data.type === 'audio-start') {
          console.log('New audio stream starting');
          const audioTracks = rtc.getReceivers()
            .filter(receiver => receiver.track.kind === 'audio')
            .map(receiver => receiver.track);
          console.log('Active audio tracks:', audioTracks);
          console.log('Track states:', audioTracks.map(track => track.readyState));
          console.log('Track enabled:', audioTracks.map(track => track.enabled));
        }
        
        if (data.type === 'audio-end') {
          const activeStreams = rtc.getReceivers()
            .filter(receiver => receiver.track.kind === 'audio')
            .map(receiver => ({
              track: receiver.track,
              state: receiver.track.readyState,
              enabled: receiver.track.enabled
            }));
          console.log('Audio stream complete, active streams:', activeStreams);
        }
        
      };
    }
  }, [ws, rtc]);

  const connectWebSocket = () => {
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    socket.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connected');
      setWs(socket);

      // Create a new RTCPeerConnection
      const rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: [
          { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }, // Public STUN server
        ],
      });

      navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      .then((stream) => {
        const audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
        // audioTrack.enabled = false; // Mute the track to avoid feedback
        rtc.addTrack(audioTrack);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error creating dummy audio track:', error);
      });


      rtc.onicecandidate = (event) => {
        console.log('ICE candidate received');
        if (event.candidate) {
          console.log('Sending ICE candidate to backend');
          socket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'ice-candidate', candidate: event.candidate }));
        }
      };


      rtc.ontrack = (event) => {
        console.log('Receiving audio stream');
        
        // Remove any existing audio elements
        const existingAudio = document.querySelector('#webrtc-audio');
        if (existingAudio) {
          existingAudio.remove();
        }
      
        // Create and configure new audio element
        const audio = document.createElement('audio');
        audio.id = 'webrtc-audio';
        audio.srcObject = event.streams[0];
        audio.autoplay = true;
        audio.controls = true;
        
        // Enable audio output
        audio.volume = 1.0;
        
        // Add error handling
        audio.onerror = (e) => {
          console.error('Audio playback error:', e);
        };
        
        // Add the audio element to the DOM
        document.body.appendChild(audio);
        
        // Ensure audio is playing
        audio.play().catch(e => {
          console.error('Error playing audio:', e);
        });
        
        // Log stream and track status
        console.log('Track enabled:', event.track.enabled);
        console.log('Track readyState:', event.track.readyState);
      };

      rtc.onicegatheringstatechange = () => {
        if (rtc.iceGatheringState === 'complete' && !offerReady) {
          console.log('ICE gathering complete, ready to send offer');
          setOfferReady(true);
        }
      };

      setRtc(rtc);
    };
  };

  const startWebRTC = async () => {
    if (!rtc) {
      console.error('RTC connection is not initialized');
      return;
    }
  
    console.log('Starting WebRTC');
    try {
      const offer = await rtc.createOffer();
      console.log('Created SDP offer:', offer);
      await rtc.setLocalDescription(offer);
  
      console.log('Waiting for ICE gathering to complete...');
      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (rtc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
          resolve();
        } else {
          const checkIceGathering = () => {
            if (rtc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
              rtc.removeEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkIceGathering);
              resolve();
            }
          };
          rtc.addEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkIceGathering);
        }
      });
  
      console.log('ICE gathering complete, sending SDP offer');
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'offer', sdp: rtc.localDescription }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating SDP offer:', error);
    }
  };
  

  const sendText = () => {
    if (ws && text) {
      console.log('Sending text:', text);
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'text', text })); // Send text to backend
      setText(''); // Clear the input field after sending
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: '20px' }}>
      <button onClick={connectWebSocket}>Connect WebSocket</button>
      <button onClick={startWebRTC}>Start WebRTC</button>
      <br /><br />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Enter text to convert to speech"
        style={{ width: '300px', marginRight: '10px' }}
      />
      <button onClick={sendText}>Send Text</button>
    </div>
  );
}

I dont receive any audio on client side.
